# Selecting a value in a JSON object based on another JSON value using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

```
{ 
     "lessons": [{
          "questionid" : "23" , 
          "Lessonname" : "Maths" , 
          "Grade" : "3"
      }] 
}

{
    "Exams": [{
        "Test": "SAT",
        "Questionid": 23,
        "grade": "3"
   }]
}
```

I have these two sample JSON arrays, And I want to  able to select Questionid from the Exams array and use it to print its corresponding lessons from the lesson array. Can anyone help ? I am using jquery.

Comment: 1st of all your json is invallid. Please add see the correct json.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //1st ajax call to get question Id
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'json.js',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            //console.log(data.Exams);
            $.each(data.Exams, function(i, val){
                //console.log(val.Questionid);
                var questionId = val.Questionid; //This is your question id

                //2nd Ajax call to get lession name
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'json2.js',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(lessonsData){
                        console.log(lessonsData.lessons);
                        $.each(lessonsData.lessons, function(j, lessonVal){
                            //console.log(lessonVal.questionid);
                            var lessonId = lessonVal.questionid;

                            if(questionId == lessonId){
                                var lessonName = lessonVal.Lessonname;
                                console.log(lessonName); //This will give you the lesson name
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Corresponding Json,

```
{
   "Exams": [
       {
          "Test": "SAT",
          "Questionid": 23,
          "grade": "3"
       }
   ]
}
{ 
    "lessons": [
       {
           "questionid" : "23" , 
           "Lessonname" : "Maths" , 
           "Grade" : "3"
       }
    ] 
}
```

Comment: The corresponding Json for the code is the above one in your question.

Comment: If you can, please format your lessons array and Exams arrays before the edit timer runs out (Object and Array open/close tags on same/different lines).

Comment: Is that ok now? @autoboxer